# WordPress 3.8+ Admin Dashboard Widget Positions

Tags: wordpress

Pre 3.8 there was simply side and core for positioning admin dashboard widgets. Now that we are in the 3.8+ world we have 4 columns. I've looked all over but I cannot seem to find anyone with an example on how to position a widget in a specific column.

For example I created a custom widget and have coded it to force itself to the top left position as seen here - http://cl.ly/image/3H1b1G052n2X

Specifically I'm asking how can I move the "Activity Widget" to the top right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable 2 columns feature, applying this filter in your theme, functions.php

```
// force one-column dashboard
function shapeSpace_screen_layout_columns($columns) {
    $columns['dashboard'] = 1;
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('screen_layout_columns', 'shapeSpace_screen_layout_columns');

function shapeSpace_screen_layout_dashboard() { return 1; }
add_filter('get_user_option_screen_layout_dashboard', 'shapeSpace_screen_layout_dashboard');
```

Source: http://digwp.com/2013/12/bring-back-single-column-dashboard-in-wp-3-8/